# ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: res

Tags: auth, kohana

делаю авторизацию, с помощью модуля auth.
Есть массив

```
if(isset($_POST['btnsub'])){
                    $login = Arr::get($_POST, 'login','');
                    $pass = Arr::get($_POST, 'password','');

                    if($auth->login($login, $pass)){
                        $res["noerror"] = "";
                    }else{
                    $res["error"] = "";
        }
    }

$this->template->content = View::factory('auth',$res);
```

вывожу

```
            <?  if(isset($error)){ ?>
                <p>Неправильно</p>
            <? } ?>
```

открываю сайт а там ошибка

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: res

$this->template->content = View::factory('auth',$res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Читать [View (Представления)](http://kohana3.ru/view) до полного просветления. Если будет уж совсем невыносимо сложно - переходите сразу к [Передача через set](http://kohana3.ru/view#передача-через-set).

*p.s.: вы на каждый чих будете вопрос задавать?*

Comment: думаю здесь людей много с опытом! Вот и спрашиваю! Но ошибку я нашел, просто забыл добавить пустой массив.